# How should I merge approximately equivalent character values? I thought edit_threshold would do the trick

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, openrefine

I come across this problem and similar ones often. I have a list or 507 restaurants but they are not 507 unique restaurants. There are duplicates but with abbreviations. There are some funny prefixes or suffixes depending on who the credit card processor was. My guess is that those 507 unique values represent somewhere around 300 to 480 unique restaurants. For me as a human, it is quite easy to decide if two different, yet similar, character string values represent the same restaurant or different restaurants. I have played with many options.

Here is a reproducible example vector of 10 unique items:
`c("Artspace & Coffeehouse", "Artspace & Coffeehou", "Artspace & Coffeehous", "Artspace & Coffeeho", "Artspace & Coffee Q48", "Artspace & Crumpet", "Stone", "Pepper", "Bakersfield", "Bakery Social")`

I want an argument to return a vector of 10 items but with only 6 unique values. "Artspace & Crumpet" would be different to all the variations of "Artspace & Coffeehouse" that make up the first 5 values. Nothing else would be merged. So we would get something such as this.

```
 [1] "Artspace & Coffeehou"  "Artspace & Coffeehou"  "Artspace & Coffeehou" 
 [4] "Artspace & Coffeehou"  "Artspace & Coffeehou"  "Artspace & Crumpet"   
 [7] "Stone"                 "Pepper"                "Bakersfield"          
[10] "Bakery Social"
```

I thought I was onto something good with the `refinr` package:

```
    library(refinr)
    restaurants <- c("Artspace & Coffeehouse", "Artspace & Coffeehou", "Artspace & Coffeehous", "Artspace & Coffeeho", "Artspace & Coffee Q48", "Artspace & Crumpet", "Stone", "Pepper", "Bakersfield", "Bakery Social")  
    n_gram_merge(vect = restaurants,  edit_threshold = 2)
```

But that is not what I get. Instead I get this.

```
 [1] "Artspace & Coffeehou"  "Artspace & Coffeehou"  "Artspace & Coffeehou" 
 [4] "Artspace & Coffeeho"   "Artspace & Coffee Q48" "Artspace & Crumpet"   
 [7] "Stone"                 "Pepper"                "Bakersfield"          
[10] "Bakery Social"
```

I was expecting that if I increased the edit_threshold even more I would get merging of "Artspace & Coffeeho" and "Artspace & Coffee Q48" but I did not. Do you have any suggestions? I also tried changing numgram to 3 or 4.

I have also played with `stringdistmatrix` and setting `method = "jw"`. I then used cutree, hclust and as.dist to create groups of values. It worked but does not do the merging for me. How do I get `n_gram_merge` to work better?

Comment: Don't you think the openrefine tag should be included? `refinr` package is an R implementation of the text clustering algorithms used in open refine. I was hoping someone with expertise in that software tool would be able to help..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `cutree(hclust(dist(stringdist::stringdistmatrix(raw, raw, method = "jw"))), h=0.5)` and considering the cutoff (h=0.5) value to optimise your code.

With that, you can group based on the first item, eg:

```
raw = c("Artspace & Coffeehouse", "Artspace & Coffeehou", "Artspace & Coffeehous", "Artspace & Coffeeho", "Artspace & Coffee Q48", "Artspace & Crumpet", "Stone", "Pepper", "Bakersfield", "Bakery Social")
groups = cutree(hclust(dist(stringdist::stringdistmatrix(raw, raw, method = "jw"))), h=0.5)
groupVal = c(1,cumsum(rle(groups)$lengths)+1)
converted = raw[groupVal[groups]]
```

Comment: That is some pretty smooth "Shim Sham Sand Dance" you did there to generate the merged vector. Impressive. I was hoping to get n_gram_merge to work better but your way is making me consider giving up on it. Maybe I should just stick to Jaro-Winkler distance.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the string matching methods to know what should work best for this scenario, but hopefully the example code is enough to show a workload that can be tweaked to work efficiently for you.